# I had removed my phone number from my website footer, but months later it still appears once I look it up on google, how to remove it?

Tags: search, seo, google, google-search

I had added my phone number for customer support assistance, but I have changed the phone number from the website, now whenever I type my phone on google search, my website appears and the phone number shows up in the meta description, even though I've removed it already months ago! I want it so that whenever I type my phone number on Google, nothing shows up. Can anybody help me with this task?

I've tried requesting indexing but the problem is still there. I have also removed some pages from Google search but new pages pop up instead (all from my website).

Answer (score 0):

It usually takes several days (or more) for search results to be updated.

First step would be to look at every single page of your site and check for the correct phone number.

Then create a new sitemap.xml file, and submit that to the various search engines (like via Google Webmaster Tools). Many articles available on how to do that. There are even sites that will analyze your site to create a sitemap.xml file.

Once you submit the new sitemap.xml file, you will have to wait for indexing to be updated. That may take a week or more, so 'patience, Grasshopper'.

(Note that your question is not related to WordPress development, so it may be closed to accepting additional answers.)

Comment: Thank you Rick, I posted it originally on stackoverflow but they suggested i come here, but apparently here too isn't the right place to ask my question. But either way thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: Hope this helps. Remember that upvoting and/or using the checkmark indicates that the answer matches your question. An upvote indicates a helpful answer. It's a reward system for people to answer questions.

Comment: I can't seem to find the button that does it

Comment: It's to the left of the answer. There is an up and down triangle for voting up/down, and a checkmark icon to mark the answer as correct.  Take a 'tour' of this site here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour